# How to store data from Tweepy's user_Lookup method into csv file?

Tags: python, csv, lookup, tweepy

I was able to print out the specific user_info using Tweepy but I would like to store the data into csv file. As is, I am getting an encoding error. How can I store the data in csv file?

```
import tweepy
import csv

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

test = api.lookup_users(user_ids=[''])
for user in test:
    #csvWriter.writerow([user.description.encode('utf-8')])

    print user.screen_name
    print user.description
    print user.followers_count
    print user.statuses_count
    print user.url

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: can you post an output of `pprint.pprint(test)` or just `print(test)`?

Comment: [User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=True, _json={u'follow_request_
sent': False, u'has_extended_profile': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'
id': 17006157, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/4431039/twitter_

Comment: it goes on in this format when print(test)

Comment: when I print "user.screen.name" it prints nicely but when I store these values into list, there's a problem with encoding since this format is in json format.

Comment: i would use pandas module for that. you can construct pandas data frame from JSON like this: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_json(json_obj)` after that you can easily save it to CSV: `df.to_csv('c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)`. If you need a working example - please post your `test` variable as a JSON object/string

Answer (score 0):

You sould be able to create your .csv file using tweepy and csv as follows,

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

csvFile = open('filename.csv', 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for user in api.lookup_users(user_ids=["id"]):
    t=user.description
    csvWriter.writerow(t)    #will print in comma separated value (each letter)
    csvWriter.writerow([t.encode('utf-8')])    #will print the whole string in one cell (row/column)

    print t

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: When I run it, I get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) @glls